# When I click "Show potential fixes" but don't choose a fix, all error underlines disappear

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

[image]

I am using VS2015 Community. When I check the potential fixes of an error but don't choose one, all curly error underlines disappear (although the errors are still in the Error List). I only get the underlines back when I edit the file and save it.

This really bothers me. Is there a settings tweak to fix this annoying behavior?

Comment: VS2015 has lots and lots of Roslyn integration bugs.  You'll have to click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues) to let them know you don't like this.